# SQL window function with where clause

Tags: sql, teradata, window-functions

I'm using teradata.
I have a table with two date columns and a product code.
Like so

```
Prod ID     StartDate       EndDate
123         1-1-2013        1-5-2013
123         1-3-2013        1-10-2013
123         1-4-2013        1-10-2013
321         1-4-2013        1-10-2013
321         1-6-2013        1-12-2013
321         1-5-2013        1-12-2013
```

I need to write a query which will give me the minimum start date of the following 'end date' for the same product. So in the above example, the first product would return '1-3-2013', and for the second product I would receive '1-5-2013' cause the next end date '1-12-2013 is a duplicate, and I just need to get the minimum instance of it's 'start date'.

I have a feeling it's something like

```
min(startDate) over (partition by prodID order by endDate rows between 1 following and 1 following)
```

However, I feel I need a qualify statement in here which will make sure that the startDate of the next row is greater than the endDate of the current row.

Comment: Can you show what you're expected output is as another table please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minimum end_date of the following rows should be

```
min(startDate) 
over (partition by prodID 
order by endDate
rows between 1 following and unbounded following)
```

Maybe you need to add startDate to the ORDER BY.

And startDate of next row greater than endDate of current row:

```
qualify
   min(startDate) 
   over (partition by prodID 
   order by endDate
   rows between 1 following and 1 following) > endDate
```